How to Train a Model to Predict Job Roles with Multi-Class Dataset?
I’m working on a project to predict job roles based on a dataset containing 39 features and 33 unique job roles as target labels. The dataset has 20,000 rows and includes both numerical and categorical columns.
Here’s a summary of the dataset:

Numerical Features (14): Percentages in academic subjects (e.g., Operating Systems, Algorithms), logical quotient rating, hackathons attended, etc.
Binary Features (16): Questions like “can work long time before system?”, “self-learning capability?”, etc.
Categorical Features (8): Includes “certifications”, “memory capability score”, “interested career area,” etc.
Target Variable: Suggested Job Role (e.g., "Database Developer", "Software Engineer", etc.).

Problem:
I preprocessed the dataset and tried training models like Random Forest, SVM, and XGBoost, but the accuracy remains consistently low (around 3%). I suspect there might be an issue with either my preprocessing, model choice, or hyperparameter tuning.
Preprocessing Pipeline:
Here’s how I preprocess the data:
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder, OneHotEncoder, MinMaxScaler

def transform_data(df):
    X = df.drop('Suggested Job Role', axis=1)
    y = df['Suggested Job Role']

    # Feature types
    two_category_features = ['can work long time before system?', 'self-learning capability?', 
                             'Extra-courses did', 'talenttests taken?', 'olympiads', 'Job/Higher Studies?',
                             'Taken inputs from seniors or elders', 'interested in games', 'Salary Range Expected', 
                             'In a Realtionship?', 'Gentle or Tuff behaviour?', 'Management or Technical', 
                             'Salary/work', 'hard/smart worker', 'worked in teams ever?', 'Introvert']

    categorical_features = ['certifications', 'workshops', 'reading and writing skills', 
                            'memory capability score', 'Interested subjects', 
                            'interested career area ', 'Type of company want to settle in?', 
                            'Interested Type of Books']

    numeric_features = ['Acedamic percentage in Operating Systems', 'percentage in Algorithms', 
                        'Percentage in Programming Concepts', 'Percentage in Software Engineering', 
                        'Percentage in Computer Networks', 'Percentage in Electronics Subjects', 
                        'Percentage in Computer Architecture', 'Percentage in Mathematics', 
                        'Percentage in Communication skills', 'Logical quotient rating', 
                        'hackathons', 'coding skills rating', 'public speaking points', 'Hours working per day']

    # Preprocessing pipelines
    two_category_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('ordinal', OrdinalEncoder())
    ])
    categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))
    ])
    numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('minmax', MinMaxScaler())
    ])

    # Combine transformations
    preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
        ('two_cat', two_category_transformer, two_category_features),
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_features),
        ('minmax', numeric_transformer, numeric_features)
    ])

    transformed_X = preprocessor.fit_transform(X)
    return transformed_X, y

Models Tried:

Random Forest: Using default parameters.
SVM: Tried with RBF kernel, default hyperparameters.
XGBoost: Default parameters.

Despite trying these models, the accuracy is stuck around 3%.

Questions:

Why might the models be underperforming on this dataset?
Are there specific techniques or approaches I should try (e.g., hyperparameter tuning, feature selection, oversampling)?
How can I better handle the high cardinality of the target variable (33 unique job roles)?


I am afraid these are not programming questions, hence they are actually off-topic here; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info for more
